# JavaScript regular expressions for a title text box field

Tags: javascript, regex

My knowledge of regular expression is very weak. I am needing help building the regular expression and try to display two notifications if user leaves title text box field empty. In my original project there is more than one text box for currency, description textarea, chekcbox, etc. But I don't want to make this example extensive so I am using only one text box.

Both notification appear if text box field is left empty but the problem is once the correct input is placed it still shows notification number two: "* Descriptive title for your post". Why is that?

**JS Expressions**

```
"required": { // Add your regex rules here, you can take telephone as an example
                    "regex": "none",
                    "alertText": "* This is required",
                    "alertTextCheckboxMultiple": "* Please select an option",
                    "alertTextCheckboxe": "* This checkbox is required",
                    "alertTextDateRange": "* Both date range fields are required"
                },

"title": {
                    "regex": "none",
                    "alertText": "* Descriptive title for your post"
                },
```

**HTML**

```
input type="text"  id="ValidField" class="validate[required,custom[title]] text-input" size="60" autocomplete="off" value=""/>
```

**Result after correct input has been entered:**
[image]

Comment: So, do you need help building your regular expressions, or using the object that contains them? Why does the object have `"regex": "none"`?

Comment: I'm failing to understand why do you need two validators to validate a blank field? I'd just remove custom[title] from class

Comment: You have not provided any functional code.  I have no idea what your problem is because you've only provided a Javascript object and an HTML tag.  Are you using a library for validation? If so, please tag it and/or mention it in your question.

Comment: Yes, Sorry for not being clear but i am using a library for validation. I only included that example. There is more than one text box in my real project. For example there is a description text area, currency, etc.

Comment: @jon I meant that you ought to mention or tag *which specific library* you are using.  You should also include the actual regex you used, if you have written one.

Comment: Out of curiosity, enter in text field (your photo shows **Descriptive title** as input) the single word **none** to see if the `alertMessage` goes away. It could be that the regex is literally set to match the word **none**.

Comment: @apsillers, I am using the library from this website [GITHUB](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) and here is a [DEMO](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html).

Comment: @arttronics, Yes you are right! the word "none" makes it go away. How can i fix that? I just wanted to go away as soon as text is typed inside textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your markup, it appears that the `regex` is currently set to match the word `none` when it validates the title.

The [**Customizations**](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#customizations) section at the Validation plugin webpage explains that this value is a `regex` pattern per your forms Title requirements.

Although that `regex` example allows letters only, a different `regex` pattern can be used to include numbers, symbols, etc. per your forms requirements.

This [**online tool**](http://www.ninjavspenguin.com/regexp.html) may be useful in testing to create the right regex.

For example, a `regex` for the Title to make sure it has something would be:
`/^(\S+)/`
This `regex` would allow the Title to have letters, space, and numbers: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\ \']+$/`

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. I +1 this answer but before I accept can you help build a regex that accepts integers, letters and special characters? So far i have this one /^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$/ but is only good for numbers and letter.. not characters.

Comment: How about using the first regex example that insures something must be present. That is good for international characters too. `/^(\S+)/`